# Unique string identifier with fixed length

Tags: java, algorithm, cryptography, uuid, uniqueidentifier

Using user email (that by default it's a unique identifier) and if I need current timestamp, I'd like to generate an alphanumeric string of 11 characters (or less) that represent a unique identifier.

First to create an ad hoc (irreversible) algorithm to do it, I'd like to know if in Java there is something.

Comment: Did you try a hash function?

Comment: you may use MD5 or SHA1 and keep only first 11 characters

Comment: An alphanumeric string of 11 characters (or less) that uniquely identifies all combinations of email addresses + timestamps? Assuming by alphanumeric you mean A-Za-z0-9, there are only 52,036,560,683,837,093,888 possible 11 character strings, and there are a lot more possible email addresses.

Comment: Do you want it to be symmetric or asymmetric? http://support.microsoft.com/kb/246071

Comment: @Alexandre Santos algorithm must me irreversible and no matter about symmetric or asymmetric because it's encrypt server side and it'll be not decryptable.

Comment: Could you give us some examples of the data?

Comment: An email (and timestamp if need) as input data...in output something like 5fGH1isb95k

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As others pointed out, it is not possible to generate a **unique alphanumeric string with length 11** from each email address, as the **alphanumeric strings with length 11** are less than all the possible email addresses. So there will always be two different email addresses e1 and e2 such that **F(e1) = F(e2) = S** for some string **S** which you generate.

Still, given an email address **e1**, you can generate a string which is (let's call it) "pseudo-unique" i.e. a string **S = F(e1)** for which it is **practically very hard** to find another email address **e2 != e1** such that **F(e2) = S**. And as others pointed out, you can use e.g. MD5 to achieve this.

Look at this class and call it on the byte array obtained from your email address.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/security/MessageDigest.html

Actually here is an example using MD5.

```
import java.security.MessageDigest;
import java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException;

public class Test003 {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        System.out.println(getPseudoUniqueString("test1@test.com"));
        System.out.println(getPseudoUniqueString("test2@test.com"));            
    }

    private static String getPseudoUniqueString(String str) 
        throws NoSuchAlgorithmException 
    {
        MessageDigest md1 = MessageDigest.getInstance("MD5");
        md1.update(str.getBytes());
        byte[] bd1 = md1.digest();

        StringBuffer hexString = new StringBuffer();
        for (int i=0;i<bd1.length;i++) {
            String hex=Integer.toHexString(0xff & bd1[i]);
            if(hex.length()==1) {
                hexString.append('0');
            }
            hexString.append(hex);
        }

        return hexString.toString().substring(0,11);
    }
}
```